# Привет! Возникла проблема в запуске генератора трафика

Tags: администрирование, cisco, сетевое-программирование, нагрузочное-тестирование

Генератор трафика Cisco TRex. При запуске команды
sudo ./dpdk_setup_ports.py -i
появляется пустой список устройств. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел [туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1lHMkYmbSc) но пока не понял как добавить сетевые интерфейсы. Использую виртуальную машину Hyper-v в связке с Ubuntu  20.04.4 LTS

Что можно почитать что посмотреть что бы эти сетевые интерфейсы появились. Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да просто хочу запустить сервер используя генератор сетевого трафика Cisco TRex.